# How can i make DateUtil throw an exception?

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

```
    @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            try{
                DateUtil.clean();
            }catch(Exception e){
                LOGGER.error("MyServletContextListener contextDestroyed error: ", e);
            }
```

I am doing unit testing on the above piece of code, and am trying to get 100% line coverage by hitting the Exception clause, however, i cant seem to make it work with my implementation. Would appreciate any help yall. Please look below for my implementation.

```
 @Test (expected= Exception.class)
    public void test_contextDestroyed_Exception() {

        DateUtil wrapper = Mockito.spy(new DateUtil());
        Exception e = mock(Exception.class);

        when(wrapper).thenThrow(e);
       Mockito.doThrow(e)
                .when(myServletContextListener)
                .contextDestroyed(sce);

        myServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(sce);
    }
```

Comment: First of you are trying to mock static method.. Try using power mock. You should write `when(DateUtil.clean ()).thenThrow(e)`

Comment: Hi @ShirishkumarBari, i tried what you mentioned, but i am getting a ''when (T) in Mockito cannot be applied to (void)    reason: no instances(s) of type variable(s) T exists so that void conforms to T." error

Comment: Try using PowerMockito

Answer (score 1):

Since `DateUtil.clean()` is a static method, you can't mock it with Mockito.
You need to use PowerMockito instead:

```
<properties>
    <powermock.version>1.6.6</powermock.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Check [official PowerMock documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki) for version compatibility with JUnit and Mockito.

Once you did that, you should add the following to your test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) //<-- this says to JUnit to use power mock runner
@PrepareForTest(DateUtil.class) //<-- this prepares the static class for mock
public class YourTestClass {
    
    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void test_contextDestroyed_Exception() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DateUtil.class);
        when(DateUtil.clean()).thenThrow(new Exception("whatever you want"));
        //prepare your test
        //run your test:
        myServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(sce);
    }
    
 
}
```

Comment: hi, I tried to type 'when(DateUtil.clean()).thenThrow(new Exception("..."));, but I am getting the following error:

''when (T) in Mockito cannot be applied to (void) reason: no instances(s) of type variable(s) T exists so that void conforms to T." error

Comment: @ben are you using the PowerMockito.when() ? Check your static import and make sure the when you are using is not the one from Mockito

Comment: Yes, i even tried 
PowerMockito.when(DateUtil.clean()).thenThrow(new Exception("whatever"));

but i still get the error Cannot resolve method 'when(void)'

Answer (score 0):

you can use `mockito-inline` artifact from Mockito to test static methods and follow the below approach,

```
try (MockedStatic<DateUtil> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(DateUtil.class)) {
            utilities.when(DateUtil::clean).thenThrow(Exception.class);
            // assert exception here
        }
```

for more info,

https://frontbackend.com/java/how-to-mock-static-methods-with-mockito